# Put image inside of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In this rock-paper-scissors game I'm working on, I want to replace the 'emoji' which is printed and taken from the array called SELECTIONS, and put an image instead of the emoji.

I already replaced the emojis in the html file with my pngs, but I also want the results to be pngs and not emojis. How do I write in the SELECTIONS array to print an image and not an emoji?

The code is taken from this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yS-JV4fWqY&t=498s

```js
const selectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-selection]')
const finalColumn = document.querySelector('[data-final-column]')
// const computerScoreSpan = document.querySelector('[data-computer-score]')
// const yourScoreSpan = document.querySelector('[data-your-score]')
const SELECTIONS = [
  {
    name: 'rock',
    emoji: '✊',
    beats: 'scissors'
  },
  {
    name: 'paper',
    emoji: '✋',
    beats: 'rock'
  },
  {
    name: 'scissors',
    emoji: '✌',
    beats: 'paper'
  }
]

selectionButtons.forEach(selectionButton => {
  selectionButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const selectionName = selectionButton.dataset.selection
    const selection = SELECTIONS.find(selection => selection.name === selectionName)
    makeSelection(selection)
  })
})

function makeSelection(selection) {
  const computerSelection = randomSelection()
  const yourWinner = isWinner(selection, computerSelection)
  const computerWinner = isWinner(computerSelection, selection)

  addSelectionResult(computerSelection, computerWinner)
  addSelectionResult(selection, yourWinner)

  if (yourWinner) incrementScore(yourScoreSpan)
  if (computerWinner) incrementScore(computerScoreSpan)
}

function incrementScore(scoreSpan) {
  scoreSpan.innerText = parseInt(scoreSpan.innerText) + 1
}

function addSelectionResult(selection, winner) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = selection.emoji
  div.classList.add('result-selection')
  if (winner) div.classList.add('winner')
  finalColumn.after(div)
}

function isWinner(selection, opponentSelection) {
  return selection.beats === opponentSelection.name
}

function randomSelection() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * SELECTIONS.length)
  return SELECTIONS[randomIndex]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title> Freeze</title>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <script src="sketch.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="selections">
    <button class="selection" data-selection="rock"><img src ="rock.png" </button>
    <button class="selection" data-selection="paper"><img src="paper.png"</button>
    <button class="selection" data-selection="scissors"><img src="scissors.png"</button>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <div>
      You
    
    </div>
    <div data-final-column>
      Computer

    </div>
    <!-- <div class="result-selection winner">✊</div>
    <div class="result-selection">✌</div> -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you can put html into `div.innerHTML`

basically change emoji into <img> element

```js
function addSelectionResult(selection, winner) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = selection.emoji
  div.classList.add('result-selection')
  if (winner) div.classList.add('winner')
  finalColumn.after(div)
}
```

better way:

```html
<img src="intial.png" id="player-result-img">
```

```js
const states = {
  rock: "rock.png",
  paper: "paper.png",
  scissors: "scissors.png"
}
function setPlayerState(state){
  document.getElementById("player-result-img").src = state
}
setPlayerState(states.rock) // the <img> element will have src of rock.png
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still haven't understood how to change the emoji. How would my code become with the changes you suggested? Could u integrate it to my code?

Comment: as i said you can change your emoji value into something like this: `emoji: "<img src="emoji.png">"`